# Custom Block in Magento catalogsearch.xml

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.5, magento-1.7

I have created a sample module Web. Also I have created one Sample Block for this. I have one web.phtml file in app/design/frontend/default/default/template folder and one web.xml file in app/desing/fronted/default/default/layout file. Below is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
    </default>
    <web_index_index>
    <reference name="root">
          <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="web/web" name="web" template="web/web.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </web_index_index>
</layout>
```

It works properly in my http://mydomain.com/magento/web.

Now I copied a catalogsearch.xml file from app/desing/fronted/base/default/layout and paste it in app/desing/fronted/default/default/layout and added block code in it after results.phtml but I am not able to see the block in my catalogsearch page.

```
<block type="web/web" name="web" template="web/web.phtml" />
```

What I am missing here? What is the proper way to add block in catalogsearch.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

The file in which a layout update directive appears is (generally) irrelevant. What scopes layout XML directives are the layout update handles.

For catalogsearch results you will want to add your block to two handles if you want it in both the simple and advanced search results views; add this to your *web.xml* layout file:

```
<catalogsearch_result_index>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="web/web" name="web" template="web/web.phtml" after="-" /> 
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_result_index>

<catalogsearch_advanced_result>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="web/web" name="web" template="web/web.phtml" after="-" /> 
    </reference>
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

Now, most developers will blanche at the thought of repeating code. The above instruction can be written once in a utility handle and then the utility handle can be used to apply the result elsewhere:

```
<web_addToContent>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="web/web" name="web" template="web/web.phtml" after="-" /> 
    </reference>
</web_addToContent>

<catalogsearch_advanced_result>
    <update handle="web_addToContent" />
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>

<catalogsearch_advanced_result>
    <update handle="web_addToContent" />
</catalogsearch_advanced_result>
```

If the block is appearing at the beginning of the content (despite `after="-"`), it may be necessary to make the web module's config XML load after the catalog search module.

Comment: Suppose I want to add block after list.phtml, so can i write here after="catalog/layer/list.phtml" ?

Comment: No. after (or before) work by using a block name. These sorting params *generally* only apply when the parent is a `core/text_list` block. If a block need to be rendered in a position in a block which uses a template, the block should be added as a child and the template must be customized to render the child.